# Why can't I log in as an admin user in my django app after creating the superuser and providing the correct details in the login form?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, multi-factor-authentication

I have a django app where I'm trying to implement a 3 layers MFA system for users. At the moment, users can signup with email and password, after which they are redirected to a page where they set up their MFA details(phone_number and recovery question/answer) before they are logged in. Upon subsequent logins, they have to pass through the three layers of authentication where they provide the email/password, recoveryquestion/answer and OTP code sent to their phone number.

All these works fine.
When I try creating a superuser, it gets created successfully too(though without setting up the MFA). But when I try logging the superuser in i get an error message that either email or password is wrong.

This is my signup view

```
def signup(request):
    '''
    Serve the signup form then get redirected to setmfa 
    page to fill in the details required to set up MFA
    '''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the values of the SignUp form in order
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            #Do stuff if the form is valid
            
            # Saves a new user object from the  form's data 
            user = form.save()

            # Save user  --- THIS LINE CREATES A USER, WHICH TRRIGGERS THE SIGNAL TO CREATE A
            #                USERPROFILE(with all fields set to the default value) FOR THE USER
            user.save()

            # Try(in a case where fr some reason the user isnt created) to get the user ID
            try:
                submitted_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                thisuser = User.objects.get(email = submitted_email)
            except:
                raise ValueError("Couldn't get user")
            

            # Save user id in session with key 'tupk(this user primary key)'
            request.session['tupk'] = thisuser.pk

            # Redirect to mfaform page to fill in the mfa details(question, answer and phone number)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("accounts:setmfa"))

        else:
            return render(request, "accounts/signup.html", {
                                    'form': form,
                                    'message': 'Form not valid'})

    # Serve the signup form in forms.py
    signupform = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': signupform})
```

My login view jurst redirects to the first page of the MFA system

```
def login_view(request):
    # Redirects to mfa view passing in 1 as an argument to 
    # route it to the first level of the MFA system
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("accounts:mfa", args=(1,),))
```

The MFA view

```
def mfa(request, level):
    '''
    Implementation for the three levels of authentication.
    
    LEVEL 1: User is served the Email/Password form
    LEVEL 2: User is served the Recovery question to provide an answer
    LEVEL 3: User is served a simple form to provide the OTP sent to their phone number upon passing level
    
    '''

    if request.method == "POST":
        # Check current MFA security level
        level = request.POST['level']

        if level == "1":
            # Get returned email and password
            email = request.POST["email"]
            password = request.POST["password"]

            # Check returned email and password
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

            # If the user email and password checks out
            if user:
                # Get user and save the user's id in session 
                user = User.objects.get(email = email)
                request.session['tupk'] = user.pk

                # Redirect to the second level of mfa
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("accounts:mfa", args=(2,),))
            else:
                # If password  doesn't check out, redirect to login view which restarts the MFA process
                # TODO Delete pk from sessions first
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("accounts:login_view"))
        
        if level == "2":
            '''
            Check if the recovery answer is correct  ---> 
            if correct, redirect to the third level
            '''
            # Get returned recovery question's answer 
            answer = request.POST["recovery_answer"]
            
            # Get user_id from session
            pk = request.session['tupk']

            # Use pk to get user, userprofile and user's recovery answer in extension
            user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
            userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)

            # Check if provided answer from form matches the user's recovery answer
            if userprofile.recovery_answer == answer:
                request.session['tupk'] = user.pk

                # Redirect to the third/last level of mfa
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("accounts:mfa", args=(3,)))
            
            # If answer doesn't checkout, redirect to login view which restarts the MFA process
            else:
                # TODO Delete pk from sessions first
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("accounts:login_view"))
            
        if level == "3":
            '''
            Check if the OTP is correct  ---> if correct, 
            log user in and redirect to journal's home page
            '''
            # Get returned recovery question's answer 
            otp_code = request.POST["otp"]
            
            # Get user_id from session and user it to get user
            pk = request.session['tupk']
            user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)

            # Check if there exists an OTPcode in the database with this code and this user
            if OTPCode.objects.filter(code=otp_code, owner=user).exists():
                '''
                If the code exists for this user...
                Clean up pk from session, delete otpcode from db 
                then log user in
                '''

                #TODO Delete pk from sessions
                if request.session['tupk']:
                    del request.session['tupk']

                # Delete OTPCode from db
                used_code = OTPCode.objects.get(code=otp_code, owner=user)    
                used_code.delete()


                # Log user in
                login(request, user)

                #Redirect to home page
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("journal:home"))

            else:
                # If the code provided doesn't checkout(isn't in the database)

                #TODO Delete pk from 

                # Redirect user to the login_view to restart the MFA 
                # process from level one
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("accounts:login_view"))

            

    if level == 1:
        # Serve the Email/Password form
        return render(request, "accounts/mfaone.html")
    if level == 2:
        '''
        Serve the Recovery question form 
        '''
        # Get user's profile from primary key in session
        pk = request.session["tupk"] 
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
        # Get the user's recovery question 
        recovery_question = profile.recovery_question

        # Serve the form to get the answer passing in the question
        return render(request, "accounts/mfatwo.html", {'question': recovery_question}) 
    if level == 3:
        ''' 
        Send an OTP to the user's phone number then serve 
        a simple form to get the OTP back
        '''
        
        # Generate a random 6 digit code 
        code = random.randint(100000, 999999)

        # Get the user for the session
        user_id = request.session['tupk']
        user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)

        # Create a OTPcode with this user as the user as the owner and save in database
        otpcode = OTPCode.objects.create(code=code, owner=user)
        otpcode.save()

        # TODO Send OTPcode to user's phone number
        # For now(before integrating Twillo we'll print the code
        print(code)


        # Serve form to get the OTPcode from the user 
        return render(request, "accounts/mfathree.html")
```